# perl regex to capture repeating group

Tags: regex, perl

I want a regular expression that matches something at the beginning of a line, and then matches (and returns) all other words. For instance, given this line:

```
$line = "one two three etc";
```

I want something like this (that doesn't work):

```
@matches= $line=~ /^one(?:\s+(\S+))$/;
```

to return into @matches, the words "two", "three", "etc".

I don't want to know how to get the words. I want to do it with a regular expression. It seems so simple, but I have not been able to come with a solution.

Comment: You can't have an "unknown" number of capture groups. You can either capture the entire string `two three etc`, define 3 capture groups, or do a global match each with one word in capture group 1.

Comment: What is wrong with split?  Using split, your code will be arguably more readable.

Comment: split is fine, but I was dissapointed that I couldn't figure out a regex

Comment: @LenJaffe because the question is how to do it with a regex. The example is irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

To do that you need to use the `\G` anchor that matches the position at the end of the last match. When you build a pattern with this anchor, you can obtain contiguous results:

```
@matches = $line =~ /(?:\G(?!\A)|^one) (\S+)/g;
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have an unknown number of capture groups. If you try to repeat a capturing group, the last instance will override the contents of the capture group:

- Expression: [`^one(?:\s+(\S+))+$`](http://regex101.com/r/tB2bF4/1)
- Capture #1: `etc`

Or:

- Expression: [`^one\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)$`](http://regex101.com/r/tB2bF4/2)
- Capture #1: `two`
- Capture #2: `three`
- Capture #3: `etc`

---

I suggest either capturing the entire group and then splitting by spaces:

- Expression: [`^one\s+((?:\S+\s*)+)$`](http://regex101.com/r/tB2bF4/3)
- Capture #1: `two three etc`

Or you can do a global match and utilize `\G` and `\K`:

- Expression: [`(?:^one|(?<!\A)\G).*?\K\S+`](http://regex101.com/r/tB2bF4/5)
- Match #1: `two`
- Match #2: `three`
- Match #3: `etc`

Comment: I think you meant `/(?:^one|(?<!\A)\G).*?(\K\S+)/g`

Comment: `\K` is not needed, but is it useful?

Comment: `\K` throws away everything matched to the left, so there is no need to capture the `\S+` since it is the only thing left matched.

Answer (score 4):

```
^.*?\s\K|(\w+)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/2

Comment: Sadly, I tried the regex in perl, but it doesn't work ... @matches is empty.

Comment: You are right. I didn't copy it correctly, so it failed. Then, I thought it was a perl issue since that link states that those are php specific regular expressions.

Comment: Further tests show that it matches regardless of the first word. For instance, it also matches this line: `$line="anything two three etc"`

Comment: @agarrubio will the first word will always be `one` ?

Answer (score 0):

The (?{...}) "execute code" special grouping could be used to memorize necessary intermediate grouping captures

Let's start from your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$line = "one two three etc";
@matches = ();
$line=~ /^one(?:\s+(\S+)(?{push @matches, $1}))+$/;
print join "\n", @matches;
```

The @matches array will have "two", "three", "etc" inside. Because (?{push @matches, $1}) being executed after the partial match will store the captured value here.

The more complicated example which could clarify this approach better:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while(<>) { $a .= $_; }
$a =~ m{cipher-suites:\s*\[[\r\n" ]+(?:([^\]]*?)[\r\n", ]+(?{push @r, $1}))+\]}sm;

print join "\n", @r;
__END__
cipher-suites: [
  "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
  "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
  "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
  "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
  "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
  "TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
]
```

This will extract ciphers into the array @r

The (?{...}) "execute code" is a very powerful regexp extension that could for instance extent regular expression with the possibility to match a nested parentheses expression.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest solution is probably to [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) after the fact:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "one two three etc";

my @matches = $line =~ /^one\s+(.*)/ ? split(' ', $1) : ();

use Data::Dump;
dd @matches;
```

Outputs:

```
("two", "three", "etc")
```

However, it's also possible to use `\G` to continue from where the previous match left off and therefore find all the non-spaces using the `/g` modifier.

The only trick is remember to not let the `\G` match at the beginning of the string so the word `one` must match:

```
my @matches = $line =~ /(?:^one|(?<!\A)\G)\s+(\S+)/g;
```